# Any tool similar to ants profiler and free?

Tags: asp.net, profiler

I want to test an asp.net web application. What are the best free graphical tools out there?

While something similar to the Ants would be really good, it would be nice to have a tool that even includes information on data sent over the wire. something like Ants + Fiddler. I hope Im not asking for too much :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Open source ones like [Nprof](http://nprof.sourceforge.net) were nice, but seem to be outdated and unmaintained.

So is [Nprofiler](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nprofiler/).

[EQATEC](http://www.eqatec.com/tools/profiler) has a promising product, but I haven't spent enough time with it yet.  Maybe next iteration. =)

I'm also eager to see other answers.

Edit: Better check out this [other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers).

Comment: EQATEC works surprisingly well...

Comment: JetBrains dotTrace and Redgate ANTS both require you to purchase a license. I need something free. Im in the middle of tryin to figure out how Eqatec works. while it seems straight forward for console or winapps.. its not the same for asp.net applications and it doesnt integrate with visual studio.

Comment: Although you can probably still get the free EQATEC profiler in some corners of the internet, it seems to have been superseded by Telerik's JustTrace: http://www.telerik.com/products/memory-performance-profiler.aspx.